# How to create a dump file in hex format from python

Tags: python-3.x, hexdump

I have a array of integer which I want to dump in one binary file (HEX file to be specific) using python script
I have written a code as

```
MemDump = Debug.readMemory(ic.IConnectDebug.fRealTime, 0, 0xB0009CC4, 0xCFF, 1)

    MemData = MemDump[:3321]
    # Create New file in binary mode and open for writing
    fp = open("MON.dmp", 'w')
    sys.stdout = fp
    for byte in MemData:
        print(byte)
```

Here MemDump contains an array of integer values. From this array first 3321 bytes I want to dump in file.
Here I am getting the the output in file MON.dmp but in ASCII fromat.
and if I create file in binary format using

```
fp = open("MON.dmp", 'wb')
```

print(byte) command gives me an error saying

```
'str' does not support the buffer interface
```

Thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert `byte` to a binary string before you can write it to a file opened in 'wb' mode. This can be done using the `bytearray()` function. So in this case you should use:

```
for byte in MemData:
    print(bytearray(byte))
```

Comment: `bytes()` function alos gives me same error

`'str' does not support the buffer interface`

Comment: `fp.write(bytearray(MemData))`

This works for me. Get the result as expected.
@Dartmouth: Thank you for giving me hint